# Download data into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, flat-file

I have a file without any extension and I need to download data into a SQL Server table.

Here's an example of one string opened in Notepad:

```
7600    20160701    20160701    20160630    20160630    20160630    ZSO ### 5501    850170371
```

In Excel it looks like one string without any spaces.

How to break string over columns when I have no comma or something like that?

Comment: It's separated with TABs, right?

Comment: show more data... Do you have a CR/LF char at the end of each line to separate records, or is it just a huge line? And @dean's question deserves an answer too .

Comment: when I copy the line from file and pasted it, looks like it has TABs but I am not sure they actualy exsits.
I don't have any char at the end of the line.
every record just begin with **7600** and ends RUB, nothing else.

Comment: SQL Server's Import Data task allows you to specify the column separator (tab perhaps?) or use fixed-width columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to check SQL Server Import wizard which is smart enough to figure out delimiter for you. You may need to validate column width and type, though.

[image]

If that is a regular activity you can create a SSIS package (you can actually create SSIS package at the end of import-export wizard) and can implement advance error handling features.

If you are looking for TSQL solution only please post more data/specification so we can work on that. it can be done in any of the following way:

- [Bulk Insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)
- [OPENQUERY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx)
- [OPENDATASOURCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx)
- [OPENROWSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For one-off tasks like this with small datasets and variable data quality, my personal preference is to use Excel to create a script which can be run in SSMS.

To accomplish this I would do the following steps:

1. Split the data using Excels "Text to columns"
   [image: Text to columns]

   - There are similar options here as in SQL Import Wizard as to how columns are calculated (fixed width/delimiters/...) with a pretty intuitive and immediate interface
2. Copy and paste special Transpose to shift the data into rows
   [image: Paste special->Transpose]

   - Possibly do some manual data cleanup
3. Add formula to "scriptify" the values
   [image: Scriptify]
4. Create and store script
   [image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use Excel (there is a function for this in german it is called (text in spalten, should be something like "text in rows") or LibreOffice Calc (it should provide a wizard) for importing the data. 
If it looks good in one of these programmes, save it as csv ore another format that you can import to MSSQL.

Comment: ETL is an entire subject area. All databases have tools to import and transform data. You *don't* need to use external tools to import simple separated or fixed-length files, there's even a wizard for this. Besides, what you call `csv` can have a lot of variations and locale-specific oddities that require special handling

Comment: Besides, *both* Excel and Calc use a wizard if you *open* a file, but *both* use locale defaults if you double-click on a file. Both are susceptible to localization issues